# Load traversed data from Binary Search Tree into Vector through header file function

Tags: c++, templates, vector, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I currently have a Vector class that is of template class, to store some stock objects. Eg. `Vector<Stock> vecA`;

In my assignment, it is a requirement to use a Binary Search Tree, perform an `inorderTraversal()` on it so it gets sorted, then do some processes with it in the `Main()`

In attempt to "hide" the traverse process from the user, and to store the sorted data after traversing the binary search tree, I'm changing the `cout << p->info` part to outputting the traversed data into an output file.

Which means:

```
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->lLink);
        cout << (p->info) << endl; //changed to vecA.Push_back(p->info);
        inorder(p->rLink);
    }
```

However, it is not pushing the items from the nodes into my vector the way I wished it would. It's technically working, I am able to `Print()` out all the rows of the data neatly, one after another, but when I do a `Vector.getLength()`, it shows that there's only 1 row.

The issue here is, when the Vector only has 1 row (but weirdly contains all the items I have and displays row after row), I can't work with this `Vector`, as most of the processes involve for-loops.

Please advise, I'm suspecting a problem with my `inorder()` method or something. Maybe it's the way a BST outputs data etc. I'm very new to BST and I'm not given much time to complete this assignment.

Here's my code for my `inorder()` function

```
    template <class elemType>
    void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
    {
    Vector<Stock> bstData;
    ofstream of("output.csv"); 
    of << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); 

    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->lLink);
        bstData.Push_back(p->info);
        inorder(p->rLink);
    }

    //Below is a for-loop that I was planning to use to get the traversed data 
    //from the Vector into an output file so I can access the traversed data 
    //through reading an output file from my Main() function

    for(int i = 0; i < bstData.getLength(); i++)
    {
        cout << "bstData data at " << i << ": " << bstData.at(i) << endl;
        //above statement is to check if i did an increment
        cout << "bstData length is: " << bstData.getLength() << endl;
        //above statement is to check my vector's length
        //the following statement is to output data from vector into a .csv file
        of << bstData.at(i).d1.getDay() << "/" << bstData.at(i).d1.getMonth() << "/" << bstData.at(i).d1.getYear() << "," << setw(2) << setfill('0') << bstData.at(i).t1.getHour() << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << bstData.at(i).t1.getMin() << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << bstData.at(i).t1.getSec() << "," << bstData.at(i).getPrice() << "," << bstData.at(i).getVolume() << "," << bstData.at(i).getValue() << endl;
        cout << "i is now at: " << i << endl; //check i again
    }
    of.close();
    } //close inorder()
```

Following is the output when I run my program:

P.S: I cannot post images so please kindly refer to this link for the image!!

http://i132.photobucket.com/albums/q28/LoveSHE911/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-17%20at%205.05.48%20am_zpstldxxags.png

Following is the output when I run `bstData.Print()` to check the contents of the vector.

http://i132.photobucket.com/albums/q28/LoveSHE911/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-17%20at%205.07.27%20am_zpsrqqo8kzb.png

Please kindly advise and help, I'm lost!

EDITS: Thanks to @Mykola, I've solved my issue as above, but one closely related problem occurred.

After performing `inorderTraversal()` in my `main()`, I wanted to do an `ifstream inFile("output.csv")` and a `while (inFile >> dd >> c >> mm >> c >> yy >> ...)` to read the file's data, create a stock object with the data, and `push_back` into an existing vector. Code as follows.

```
    ifstream inputfile("output.csv"); //open user chosen data file
    //load traversed data from output file output.csv into vAll 
    while (inputfile >> dd >> c >> mm >> c >> yy >> hh >> c >> mn >> c >> ss >> ch1 >> ch2 >> pr >> vl >> tp) 
    {   //check if there's remaining data in input file
        Stock stk2(dd, mm, yy, hh, mn, ss, ch1, ch2, pr, vl, tp); 
        //if there's still remaining data, create new stock object
        vAll.Push_back(stk2); //Insert stock object into vector 
    }
        cout << vAll.getLength() << endl; //check vector length
```

However, vAll.getLength() returns 0. Is there an obvious mistake I'm not seeing?

Comment: you can try to use vector's size() method and use standard vector class probably.

Comment: I think the problem could be in `vAll` container, because all input code seams to be ok.

Comment: @Mykola vAll has been declared as `Vector<Stock> vAll;` under a template class that I wrote and used for earlier parts of my project as well. I'm not sure if anything's wrong.. I used the same template class to create `bstData` as well.

Comment: @Mykola It is inserting now, but only the first row of the file.

Comment: It seams to be something wrong with your file. Try to check it formatting and content.

Comment: Contents are in this format in a .csv file: 11/11/2013 04:10:33PM 107 666 666.66 A total of 5 columns, that's it. I can't seem to see anything wrong. 
This is the first row, which is also the row that was able to be read into my vector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must rebuild your function to pass the storage target with node pointer. It means

```
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p, Vector<Stock>& storage) const
```

so entire code will have one more function

```
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p) const
{
    Vector<Stock> bstData;
    ofstream of("output.csv"); 
    of << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2); 

    inorder(p, bstData); // fill bstData recursively

    for(int i = 0; i < bstData.getLength(); i++)
    {
        cout << "bstData data at " << i << ": " << bstData.at(i) << endl;
        //above statement is to check if i did an increment
        cout << "bstData length is: " << bstData.getLength() << endl;
        //above statement is to check my vector's length
        //the following statement is to output data from vector into a .csv file
        of << bstData.at(i).d1.getDay() << "/" << bstData.at(i).d1.getMonth() << "/" << bstData.at(i).d1.getYear() << "," << setw(2) << setfill('0') << bstData.at(i).t1.getHour() << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << bstData.at(i).t1.getMin() << ":" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << bstData.at(i).t1.getSec() << "," << bstData.at(i).getPrice() << "," << bstData.at(i).getVolume() << "," << bstData.at(i).getValue() << endl;
        cout << "i is now at: " << i << endl; //check i again
    }
    of.close();
} //close inorder()
```

and main recursive function

```
template <class elemType>
void binaryTreeType<elemType>::inorder(nodeType<elemType> *p, Vector<Stock>& storage) const
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        inorder(p->lLink, storage); // Fill storage with left values 
        storage.Push_back(p->info); // Add current value to storage (actualy bstData).
        inorder(p->rLink, storage); // Fill storage with right values
    }
} //close inorder()
```

To load your data from file try to do that

```
while (inputFile.good()) // if stream is good
{   
    inputfile >> dd >> c >> mm >> c >> yy >> hh >> c >> mn >> c >> ss >> ch1 >> ch2 >> pr >> vl >> tp;
    //check if there's remaining data in input file
    Stock stk2(dd, mm, yy, hh, mn, ss, ch1, ch2, pr, vl, tp); 
    //if there's still remaining data, create new stock object
    vAll.Push_back(stk2); //Insert stock object into vector 
}
cout << vAll.getLength() << endl; //check vector length
```

I think you also must rewrite your reading operation

```
inputfile >> dd >> c >> mm >> c >> yy >> hh >> c >> mn >> c >> ss >> ch1 >> ch2 >> pr >> vl >> tp;
```

istream does not support formatted input so you must probably parse data in different way or use `fscanf` wich support this feature.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was asking for! It's working well now and my Vector has proper length now!

Comment: @Clare Lim: Good luck!

Comment: Hey, quick question. 
After performing inorderTraversal() in my main(), I wanted to do an ifstream inFile("output.csv") and a

while (inFile >> dd >> c >> mm >> c >> yy >> .... continue) //just to read the data { Stock stk2(dd, mm, yy, hh, mn, ss, ch1, ch2, pr, vl, tp); //create stock object, then perform a push_back on another vector with "vAll.Push_back(stk2);" }

However, vAll.getLength() returns 0. Is there an obvious mistake I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Clare Lim: If you do so all values will goes to right branch of a tree. So the tree becomes simple linked list. To deal with it you must implement some sort of rebalancing operation.

Comment: Is there any other way to simply load the file (traversed bst data) into a vector without much trouble so I can perform for-loops on that vector? I actually just needed them to be sorted according to some price value, which has been done previously with your kind help.

Comment: @Clare Lim: Could you post some code to your question?